# Which models are these aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-identification

[image]

Can somebody please identify the second aircraft. I tried reverse search but no use :C.
I'm trying to win a boeing 777 model :D

Comment: Will we get part of the 777???? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DC-9 (probably a DC-9-10 but not 100% sure), BAC-111, and Sud Aviation Caravelle, from top to bottom.

Comment: It is a DC-9-10. Only the -10 had the wing fences and the different sweep angle at the trailing edge of the wingtip

Comment: You could improve this answer by providing other pictures of the aircraft for comparison.